# Why is omega-guard giving me an error?

Tags: drush, theming

I installed drush on Mac and tried running drush omega-guard from within my theme directory like I had done before on linux. However I keep getting this error:

> The drush command 'omega-guard' could not be found.  Run `drush [error] cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have
>   installed new extensions.

I have no idea what to do about this. I saw further on down in the error log that it was trying to connect to Site URI: http://default. I have my Site located in my Dropbox folder so the location of the actual drupal site would be Dropbox/Sites/drupal. I also have an alias set for this so I can visit it at drupal.dev in the browser. I don't know how to communicate this to Drush (nor why it is necessary all of the sudden).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!